# Angular2: res.json is not a function

Tags: angular

I am trying to use the following service in my code:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response} from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService{
    constructor(private http : Http){}

    getData(){
      return  this.http.get("URI")
      .map( (res: Response) => res.json()  );
    }
}
```

The problem is, in run time it complains with:

```
res.json is not a function
```

I have defined the datatype of res as Response, but still complains

```
.map( (res: Response) => res.json()  )
```

if i replace the map with subscribe it works fine:

```
.subscribe( res =>{
                res.json();
                console.log("City is:"+ res.json().city.name)
            });
```

Comment: Are you sure your request is returning json?

Comment: I had this issue when I had functionA() calling functionB() and both used a call to map().  By the time functionA map() was called B's map had already transformed the res.json() into an array of objects which meant that A had no json available.  Fix was to remove the map() call from functionB(), so only the top level map() was called

Answer (score 18):

For what its worth, in Angular 5 I found that the `res.json is not a function` error can be fixed by just returning `res` if the response is pure json.

Answer (score 6):

Try to `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` instead of `import 'rxjs/Rx';`. That should fix the problem.

Comment: Unless the result is not correct JSON, I believe Stefan is right.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @TobySpeight If I had an explanation, don't you think I would provide it? I had the same problem a few days ago and this is how I fixed it. I can't think of any reason why `import 'rxjs/Rx'` wouldn't work because reference to `rxjs/add/operator/map` exists in `Rx.js` file, so I guess it is some sort of bug, but I'm not 100% sure, so I didn't mention it at all, just wanted to provide fix for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You Don't need to use this: 
`.map((res: Response) => res.json() );` 
or 
`.map(res => res.json());` because `HttpClient.get()` feeds or applies to  `res.json()` automatically and returns `Observable<HttpResponse<string>>`.

You no longer need to call this function yourself again. Just simply put it this way: `.map(res => res );` this resolves or solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to  call `res.json()` if you response is already a Json you can directly work with `res` you do not even need to use `map` in this case

```
  getData(){
  return  this.http.get("URI");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to put only like this

```
.map((response: Response) => response)
```

This work surely in Angular