# Error after download file - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, download, blob, arraybuffer

I have a function that performs a data download. It generates a .xlsx file. It works as expected. The function is

```
public downloadData(employeesFiltered: boolean){

this.DataService.getDataDownload(this.DataService.getDataObject(), employeesFiltered)
.subscribe((data: Response) => {
  let fileName = this.utility.getFileName(data.headers);
  let contentType = this.utility.getContentType(data.headers);

  let blob: Blob = new Blob([data.arrayBuffer()], {type: contentType});
  console.log(blob);

  let a = window.document.createElement("a");
  a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.download = fileName;

  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);

}
```

The problem is that after this is completed, no matter what I do in the app, it throws an error saying

> RangeError: byte length of Uint16Array should be a multiple of 2

And also,

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 筛 in JSON at position 0

Log below

[image: Error shown in console]

Somehow, looks like the following calls to the API get corrupted.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try to use the `body` of the `data: Response` something like that `let blob: Blob = new Blob([data['_body']], {type: contentType});`?

Comment: Nop. Same result.

Comment: What do you have on the line 204 of `backend.service.ts` ? It seems that your program is complaining about the syntax of the instruction on this line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be related not to the download itself but to the way you are handling the exception. I guess, it is related to this error `error.json is not a function`.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008411/typeerror-error-json-is-not-a-function) that might be what you need.

Comment: I know the exception is not well handled but that is not the issue.

Comment: But could you please show the code of your service?